# How can i focus all class fields whose value is empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, array.prototype.map

```
<input type ="text" class="searchskill" value=""> 
<input type ="text" class="searchskill" value="3"> 
<input type ="text" class="searchskill" value=""> 
<input type ="text" class="searchskill" value="4">
```

How can I focus all class fields whose value is empty?

```
var skillname =$(".searchskill").map(function() {
  if($(this).val()==''){
      return false;
   }
}).get();

if(jQuery.isEmptyObject(skillname)){
} else {
    alert("You Can Not Keep Skill Name As Blank"); 
    $(".searchskill").css({"border-style": "solid", "border-color": "red"});
    $(".searchskill").focus();
    return false;
}
```

I want to focus only those which are empty... How can I resolve this?

Comment: You’re aware that you can only focus one field at a time, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to get all textboxes whose value is blank and than do other stuff please find snippets as below

```js
$(".clssubmit").on("click", function() {
  var filteredList = $('.searchskill').filter(function() {
    return $(this).val() == "";
  });
  if (filteredList.length > 0) {
    filteredList.css("border", "1px solid red");
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="searchskill" value="">
<input type="text" class="searchskill" value="3">
<input type="text" class="searchskill" value="">
<input type="text" class="searchskill" value="4">

<input type="button" value="submit" class="clssubmit" />
```

Comment: there are lot of input texts are there. apart from this

Comment: I have updated my answer just apply same class on inputs on which you have to focus

Comment: where do i have to write reurn false..?

Comment: @AbdulWaheed I have updated my snippet please take a look

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(".searchskill").each(function() {
    if($(this).val() === "") {
        $(this).css({"border-style": "solid", "border-color": "red"});
    }
});
```

Comment: Using `.map` without a return value is just wasting a feature. Use `.each` instead

Comment: @Rajesh i have edited my post but I cant get you sorry

Comment: If you're using `.each()` then don't use variable to store it. He wants to say that you're using a variable extra which stores nothing if you're not returning anything.

Comment: where do ihave to write return false..?

Comment: @AbdulWaheed in if condition

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using jQuery;

```
var $inputs = $(".searchskill");
 for (let i = 0, iLen = $inputs.length; i < iLen; i++) {
       var $elem = $($inputs[i]);
       if($elem.val()===""){
       $elem.parent("div").addClass("border-red alert-danger");
       $elem.focus();
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In my understanding, by `focus`  you mean `highlight` all elements. If that is true, you can try `attribute` selector.

```js
$(function(){
  $('.searchskill[value=""]').addClass('error')
})
```

```css
.error{
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type ="text" class="searchskill" value=" "> 
<input type ="text" class="searchskill" value="3"> 
<input type ="text" class="searchskill" value=""> 
<input type ="text" class="searchskill" value="4"> 
<input type ="text" class="searchskill" value=""> 
<input type ="text" class="searchskill" value="4"> 
<input type ="text" class="searchskill" value=""> 
<input type ="text" class="searchskill" value="4">
<input type ="text" class="searchskill" value=""> 
<input type ="text" class="searchskill" value="4"> 
<input type ="text" class="searchskill" value=""> 
<input type ="text" class="searchskill" value="4">
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be simpler with selectors.

```js
// highlight all empty fields and focus on the first one
$('.searchskill[value=""]').css({"border-style": "solid", "border-color": "red"})[0].focus();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type ="text" class="searchskill" value=""> 
<input type ="text" class="searchskill" value="3"> 
<input type ="text" class="searchskill" value=""> 
<input type ="text" class="searchskill" value="4">
```